# RDweb certificate issue

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have a problem with the following system:

- There is a Windows 2012 R2 TS farm with 2 node, a gateway and a broker
- It's available externally from login.example.com
- There is an AD too, the TS farm servers are member servers, the AD domain is example.local

The problem: I would like to allow users to access this system without any warning or any certificate installation requirements. The computers are non-AD computers and there is no way to make them AD-member.

Things what i tried or thinked around:

- I tried to get a free StartSSL certificate to login.example.com but after I installed it, the TS session starting broke because name mismatch.
- I tried to make a selfsigned certificate that was issued to tsgw.example.local but the problem was opposite: even if I installed the cert, browsers complained about name mismatch.
- As I know, there is no public CA what allow to issue a cert with public common name, but a private altname/additional DNS name.
- The forums / SO/SF topics what I discovered are recommends to make a private CA and issue a cert with that (it's able to issue cert to both name) but it's our last plan, because we really don't want to force users to install a CA certificate to use our service (as they're non-AD computers, there is no automatic way to enforce trusting our CA) if there is a way to avoid that.

Is there any solution for this problem? I would like be satisfied if there is a way to enforce RDweb to ignore name mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was easier than I expected. You have to navigate in Server Manager to a Remote Desktop management interface, edit deployment properties and change all certificates in "Certificates" tab to the external certificate. In inter-server communication the services do not use an SSL-encrypted connection (just pure RPC), so they can simply ignore the certificate you install. However, in the client-server communication, this certificate will be used, so it's very important to be same in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you buy an SSL cert from an authority?
I was configuring a similar setup recently and I both one from here: https://www.namecheap.com/
It's called PositiveSSL and costs around $6.
After your server is configured with this one you won't get an SSL error.

Comment: And their CA certificate is included in Windows root certificates? We can use onl CAs what already included in that package.